# windows phone 7.1 listBoxItem having Text and value

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Is there a way i can set listBoxItem  Content as well as another hidden value (simply a id or somthing)
to?

Comment: you can use the `Tag` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use [DisplayMemberPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and [SelectedValuePath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvaluepath%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) on the `ListBox` that contains them.  If your data items are objects  of class `Foo` with properties `Text` and `ID`, then use:

```
<ListBox DisplayMemberPath="Text" SelectedValuePath="ID"
    ... />
```